# how to obtain google user credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, gcloud, rpa

i need to obtain google user credentials  using gcloud cli command and gcloud sdk.

obtain google user credentials process which includes ->

1. creating new project.
2. Enabling api and services
3. Selecting services(Ex: Cloud vision api,Maps)
4. Creating Service Account and assigning ownership.
5. Creating Credentials (Json)

I need to implement above process using script.
-please help me if anyone knows documentation or any tutorial link for above process.

Comment: Where will run your script? On Google Cloud?

Answer (score 0):

It's considered bad form to ask questions without including details of an attempt to solve the problem for yourself. I'm assuming good faith and that you're genuinely unable to find documentation for this. Your question is more about writing shell scripts than a specific issue with `gcloud`.

If you're using bash something of the form:

```bash
# Variables
BILLING=[YOUR-BILLING-ID]
PROJECT=[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]
SERVICES=(
  "vision"
  ...
)
ACCOUNT=[YOUR-ACCOUNT-NAME]

# See: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles
ROLE=[GOOGLE-IAM-ROLE]

# Create Google Cloud Project
gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}

# Link the Project with a Billing Account
gcloud beta billing projects link ${PROJECT} \
--billing-account=${BILLING}

# Enable Google services
for SERVICE in "${SERVICES[@]}"
do
  gcloud services enable ${SERVICE}.googleapis.com \
  --project=${PROJECT}
done

# Create a Service Account
gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

EMAIL=${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com

# Create a Service Account Key
# This is generally discouraged as Keys increase security risk
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Revise the Project's (!) IAM policy
# Permit the Service Account
# To use the Role
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--role=${ROLE} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL}

# Optional: Application Default Credentials
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json
```

Comment: Thank u for your response... I have tried same... I have a doubt that to do this the project should be billed?? Or we can create credentials without billing?.

Comment: It depends on the services you enable **not** the credentials.